# Red5 server project maven build failed

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, red5

I tried to build Red5 server project via Maven build and got following error after getting download updated repository files into my source is mentioned as follows -

```
 [INFO] Total time: 20.141s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 24 19:32:42 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/31M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-assembly) on project red5-server: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Files.isSymbolicLink(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Z
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.4/maven-assembly-plugin-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.2.1/maven-reporting-api-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1/doxia-sink-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1/doxia-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/1.4/maven-common-artifact-filters-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.1/file-management-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.1/maven-filtering-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.4/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.6/plexus-io-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-repository-builder/1.0-alpha-2/maven-repository-builder-1.0-alpha-2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-RC4, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

*My source code is bug free during compilation but gives above error on build*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Maven version? Full pom file?

Comment: plz find Pom.xml in my Answer.

Comment: [**find pom.xml here**](http://122.160.124.118/testxml/pom.xml)

Comment: Is this inside Eclipse? There was a [bug in m2e](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-dev/msg01548.html) that caused errors rather like this...

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly find Pom.xml file 


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>red5-server</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Red5 :: Server</name>
    <description>The Red5 server</description>
    <groupId>org.red5</groupId>
    <version>1.0.2-RC4</version>
    <url>https://code.google.com/p/red5/</url>
    <inceptionYear>2005</inceptionYear>
    <organization>
        <name>Red5</name>
        <url>https://code.google.com/p/red5</url>
    </organization>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache 2</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <mailingLists>
        <mailingList>
            <name>red5-interest</name>
            <post>https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/red5interest</post>
        </mailingList>
    </mailingLists>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>google-code</system>
        <url>https://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/list</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>Dominick Accattato</id>
            <email>dominick@red5.org</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Paul Gregoire</id>
            <email>mondain@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Dan Rossi</id>
            <email>electroteque@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
        <developer>
            <id>Tiago Jacobs</id>
            <email>tiago.jacobs@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <red5-io.version>1.0.2</red5-io.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <mina.version>2.0.7</mina.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <classpathContainers>
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                            <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4</classpathContainer>
                        </classpathContainers>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/org/red5/server/Bootstrap.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/org/red5/server/Shutdown.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/org/red5/server/jmx/mxbeans/ShutdownMXBean.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/org/red5/classloading/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bootstrap</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>bootstrap</classifier>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                    <mainClass>org.red5.server.Bootstrap</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <SCM-Revision>${buildNumber}</SCM-Revision>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/org/red5/server/Bootstrap.class</include>
                                <include>**/org/red5/server/Shutdown.class</include>
                                <include>**/org/red5/server/jmx/mxbeans/ShutdownMXBean.class</include>
                                <include>**/org/red5/classloading/**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/server.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>javadoc-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
                    <includeDependencySources>false</includeDependencySources>
                    <dependencySourceIncludes>
                        <dependencySourceInclude>org.red5:*</dependencySourceInclude>
                    </dependencySourceIncludes>
                    <detectOfflineLinks>false</detectOfflineLinks>
                    <stylesheetfile>javadoc.css</stylesheetfile>
                    <links>
                        <link>http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api</link>
                        <link>http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs</link>
                        <link>http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs</link>
                        <link>http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api</link>
                        <link>http://www.slf4j.org/api</link>
                        <link>http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs</link>
                        <link>http://groovy.codehaus.org/api</link>
                        <link>http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api</link>
                        <link>http://ehcache.org/apidocs</link>
                    </links>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>
                            <name>todo</name>
                            <!-- todo tag for all places -->
                            <placement>a</placement>
                            <head>To do:</head>
                        </tag>
                    </tags>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.flv</include>
                    <include>**/*.mp3</include>
                    <include>**/*.mp4</include>
                    <include>**/*.m4a</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Red5</id>
            <url>http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo1.maven.org</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.snapshot</id>
            <name>SpringSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>opensymphony-releases</id>
            <name>Opensymphony Releases</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/opensymphony-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mp4parser-releases</id>
            <name>MP4Parser Releases</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/comgooglecodemp4parser-137</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <name>Sonatype Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <name>Sonatype Releases</name>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Maven Repository Group</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                <artifactId>mina-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${mina.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mina.version}</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${mina.version}</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
            <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${mina.version}</version>
            <type>bundle</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.4</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-core-2.0.4.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.4</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-integration-beans-2.0.4.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.4</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-integration-jmx-2.0.4.jar</systemPath> 
            <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> 
            <artifactId>mina-core</artifactId> <version>2.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version> <scope>system</scope> 
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> </dependency> 
            <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-beans</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-integration-beans-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-jmx</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version> <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/mina-integration-jmx-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> 
            <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.apache.mina</groupId> <artifactId>mina-integration-ognl</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>20040616</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.groboutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>groboutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.mp4parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>isoparser</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC-19-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!-- <scope>system</scope> <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/isoparser-1.0-RC-19-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.red5</groupId>
            <artifactId>red5-io</artifactId>
            <version>${red5-io.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <!-- 
            <scope>system</scope> 
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/red5-io-1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
             -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the solution?!